# Generating a completely blank page from a Vue Router navbar

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to generate a blank page after the user clicks on a navbar button.

I imported a Vue router to my project on codepen.

```
    var demo = new Vue({
    
    // A DOM element to mount our view model.
    el: '#main',

    // This is the model.
    // Define properties and give them initial values.
    data: {
        active: 'what'
    },

    // Functions we will be using.
    methods: {
        makeActive: function(item){
            // When a model is changed, the view will be automatically updated.
            this.active = item;
        }
    }
});
```

When I click on How, and About in the navbar, the text successfully changes to

```
"You chose: How/about"
```

so I know the navbar code is working. But I want to generate a completely fresh page.

When I click on How or About, I want the front page text to completely disappear, and a new page to appear for the user.  How do I make the title page text disappear, and generate a completely new, black page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Vue Router you will need to import that into your application when you create your Vue instance with the new Vue({...}) command. In your example above you are not including Vue Router.

If you include VueRouter you will have to create a routes page that has routes for /how and /about. Then in your Nav you will need to surround the links for these two routes with:

`<router-link to="/how">How</router-link>`
`<router-link to="/about">About</router-link>`

These routes will then open the appropriate component you specify in the routes page.

Comment: I need to import Vue Router. I'll try later, and then accept this if it works

Comment: Answer accepted. I still had a few issues:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548478/vue-router-navbar-element-not-showing-div