# Vue Router Navbar Element not showing div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm integrating a Vue Router into a navbar.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/jOVQPWv

This codeblock works fine, and reveals either the home template, or about template on click.

```
<template id="navigation">
  <div>
    <router-link to="/"  class="">Home </router-link>
    <router-link to="/about"  class="">About</router-link>      
  </div>
</template>
```

The links Home and About in the top left hand corner show the correct template.

I added a li element "Router" to the main navbar. On hover, the Router element doesn't show a pointer. On click, it does not trigger the correct template.

```
<li>
  <router-link to="/about" class="nav__menu-item"> RouterAbout</router-link>
<li>
```

How can I make the RouterAbout element trigger the about template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML is invalid and `<div id="main">` is not inside your app `<div>` so it's not actually registered as part of the app.  It also has an undefined `active` prop.

Move `#main` into `#router-app`:

```html
<div id="router-app">
  <navigation></navigation>
  <router-view></router-view>

  <div id="main">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fixed [demo](https://codepen.io/sh0ber/pen/ZEBmQRj)

Comment: Your answer makes sense. I should have thought about scope and placement. Accepted. Thanks.